# Series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh(\pi n)}= \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma^2 \left( \frac{3}{4}\right)}-1\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I was playing around with *Mathematica* and found that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\cosh(\pi n)} = \frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma \left(\tfrac34\right)^2}-1\right)$$

Does anybody know how to prove this manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a short sketch which I might further expand on later.

Consider the equivalent [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html)

$$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{q^k}{1+q^{2k}}$$

with $q=\exp(-\pi)$.

This sum, through the use an appropriate geometric series, can also be expressed as

$$2\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\frac{q^{2j+1}}{1-q^{2j+1}}$$

This sum can be expressed in terms of the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_3(0,q)$. Using formula 57 in the previously given link, we have the expression

$$\frac{\vartheta_3(0,q)^2-1}{2}\tag{1}$$

Formula 45 in that same link gives the relation

$$\vartheta_3(0,\exp(-\pi))=\frac{\sqrt[4]\pi}{\Gamma(3/4)}\tag{2}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ gives the identity in the OP.

If you're interested in hyperbolic sums like these, you will want to see [these](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0505055) [three](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0510019)
[papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0515031).

Answer (score 6):

This is by no means obvious. First, see the MathWorld page on [Hyperbolic Secant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSecant.html).

There you will see that this identity is due to Ramanujan.

Namely, it follows from the [Ramanujan cos/cosh identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanCosCoshIdentity.html).

To prove this manually, then, you may wish to read up on how this latter identity is established.

Comment: Thanks B.D! I had heard about  Ramanujan cos/cosh identity but did not know it could be used to prove this series.

Answer (score 0):

it possible to gives
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2 \cosh \left(\pi ^2 k\right)}=\frac{i \psi _e^{(0)}\left(1+\frac{i \pi }{2}\right)}{2 \pi }-\frac{i \psi _e^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{i \pi }{2}\right)}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4 \pi }$$