# Evaluating a sum with $\cosh$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

In my integration adventures, I ran into this sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh(\pi an)(4n^{2}-1)}$$

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh(\pi n)}$ has a [nice closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352776/series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1-cosh-pi-n-frac12-left-frac?rq=1), so I was wondering if this sum does as well.

If no closed form exists (or it's hard to find) for all $a$, I would be interested in evalutating the sum when $a$ is given a set (but nonzero) value, like $a=1$ or $a=\frac 1 \pi$.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of pencil and paper at the moment, but given the symmetry of the summand, you may be able to evaluate it using contour integration against the function $\pi \cot (\pi z)$. Assuming you haven't solved it yet that is.

Answer (score 1):

Maple easily evaluates the sum under consideration:
$$S:= a\mapsto \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{\cosh \left( \pi \,an
 \right)  \left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right) }},
$$
$$evalf(S(1))=0.029009296189396298541.$$
$$plot(S,0..Pi)$$
[image]

Comment: This is numerical.  I am looking for a closed form in terms of common functions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $|e^{a \pi}|<1$, you can rewrite $\cosh (a \pi n)=\frac{e^{a \pi n}+e^{-a \pi n}}{2}$, so your denominator becomes $\frac{e^{a \pi n}}{2}<(e^{a \pi n}+e^{-a \pi n})(4n^2-1)<2e^{a \pi n}$, hence your infinite sum is upper-bounded by 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-a \pi k} < S<4 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-a \pi k}
$$
which converges and should give you good upper and lower bounds